# How to set limit for excel parser Drupal 7

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I am importing users from Excel sheet with Feed importers. In my local WAMP server I can import more than 170 users. But when I am trying on my server, it is not working. It's showing:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path: /batch?id=2906&op=do StatusText: Internal
>   Server Error ResponseText:

So I thought of limit by code. So I am using `HOOK_feeds_after_parse` where I will get all `$results`. I am counting the results with `count($results)`, if it is less than 150 then show a `message(drupal_set_message())`.

It is stopping if it is more than 150 but giving more errors like username and email is missing. Can you please help me with this? Alternatively, is there anyway to limit number rows to the parser?